# Legend displayed wrongly, one entry is out of the box, one is inside

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend

I just wanted to add a very simple legend to my plots. But every time I want to add a legend, it displays it as can be seen in the picture:

[image: Picture with the problem]

One entry has a very long line and the second entry is on the border of the box which makes it impossible to use this graphic for anything.

The code is pretty simple:

```
x=1:0.2:100;
y1=sin(x);
y2=sin(x+1);
x=x/100*6;
figure;
plot(x,y1);
hold on;
plot(x,y2)
legend('Referenzkanal 1','Referenzkanal 2')
```

What is the problem and how to fix it?

I'm using MATLAB R2017a on a Lenovo Thinkpad with Windows 10.

Comment: Can you show your code that recreates the problem, in essense a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I dont have r2017a to test against, but as I said your code looks fine and works fine (for me in r2015b) - try simple 1 character legends and build it up to see if it is a specific char length your have an issue with...

Comment: not reproducible in R2017a (Win 10). See [MCVE]

Comment: I know that it should work fine, because the code is very simple, but the problem is, that i don't have any clue why it does this. do you have an idea what i could change so it looks normal again? because this happens also to any other legend i try to display.. :-(

Comment: Restart MATLAB.

Comment: I tried that already.

Comment: If it happens for single char as well - your better contacting matlab support as its not something that your going to get help with here as its very unique.

Comment: Try using the alternative way of calling `legend` with a  cell array, i.e. `legend({'series1', 'series2'})`

Comment: Thank you very much. I contacted the matlab support :-)